# java arraylist : same values to a new arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void rechnung(List<String> array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                System.out.println(array.get(i)
                        + " gleich "
                        + array.get(j)
                        + " "
                        + (array.get(i).substring(0, 9).equals(array.get(j)
                                .substring(0, 9))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to put the values with the same date from one List into a new List. At the end I have, for example, three new lists.

List content:

03.07.2007 00001.tif  
03.07.2007 00002.tif  
18.02.2008 00003.tif  
18.02.2008 00004.tif  
18.02.2008 00005.tif  
11.03.2009 00004.tif  
11.03.2009 00005.tif

Comment: I believe the implicit question is how to get those three lists.

You may be better served by keeping just one list, but make it a list of objects that hold what you want. 

E.g., Create an object that has a "date" property, and an "imageList" property (that is a List), and then put those objects into a list.

Answer (score 0):

What about `List<String> copiedList = (List<String>) array.clone();` ?
Or `List<String copiedList = new ArrayList<String>(array);`?

Note: I highly recomment not using the variable name `array` for a `List<>`. Arrays[] are arrays and lists are lists. Nothing common if strictly regarded.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` has a constructor that can take another list.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(oldList);
```